# Securing Tapestry eventhandlers with Annotations

Tags: java, annotations, tapestry

How may I secure single eventhandlers by annotations?
I know how to secure Complete pages, but i have no idea how to check before invocation if a a method has an annotation.

Is this possible?

I dont want to use Spring-security

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ChenillKit access is a nice module.
There is also the [tapestry-security](http://tynamo.org/tapestry-security+guide) module based on the security framework Apache Shiro which provides annotation like

```
@RequiresPermissions("news:delete")
  public void onActionFromDeleteNews(EventContext eventContext) {
     ...
  }
```

Comment: tapestry-security seems to have no active development. Last release June 2011 with only 2 changed issues. I'm using tapestry 5.3, dont know if this is supported. ChenillKit seems to be out of deveopment since 2008-2009

Comment: As 5.3 according to this thread http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.tynamo.user/419 I guess that there will be a new version of Tapestry-security soon.

Answer (score 1):

With the [Chenillekit access](http://www.chenillekit.org/chenillekit-access/index.html) module you can use the [@Restricted](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/chenillekit/chenillekit-access/1.3.2/chenillekit-access-1.3.2-javadoc.jar!/org/chenillekit/access/annotations/Restricted.html) annotation on an Event method as well like so:

```
@Restricted(role = YOUR_ROLE_CONSTANT)
@OnEvent(value="eventName")
private Object handleEvent() throws Exception {
    ... your event code ....
}
```